# How to display array of objects in table getting dynamically from backend in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm getting data from backend in a dynamic manner which is based in user selection. Now, I need to display that data in the table. Can anyone help me with it?

For ex : I will get data like this from backend for the first time when user selects only 2 fields

```
{
 "result":[
  {
   "c3":"test_customer1",
   "penddel":"3029"
  },
  {
   "c3":"test_customer2",
   "penddel":"7976"
  },     
 ]
}
```

And when second time when user selects more fields data comes for that fields
For ex:

```
{
 "result":[
  {
   "c3":"test_customer1",
   "penddel":"3029"
   "c5":"testc1"
  },
  {
   "c3":"test_customer2",
   "penddel":"7976"
   "c5":"testc2"
  },     
 ]
}
```

So everytime data comes based on the user selection of fields, need to display this data dynamically in table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the data as normal and then just use object keys to pull the headings from the result.

We can then use this array to render the table headings.

Once the table headings are rendered we can then map the data and iterate through each item whilst mapping the previous heading array to render each value.

### Using React Class API

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
    
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  
  fetchData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve({
      "result": [{
          "id": "1",
          "name": "john",
          "age": "35"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "johnson",
          "age": "25"
        }
      ]
    })).then((response) => {
      this.setState({ data: response.result });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (!data) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    const headings = Object.keys(data[0]);
    
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            {headings.map((heading) => <th>{heading}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((row) => (
            <tr>
              {headings.map((heading) => <td>{row[heading]}</td>)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="root" class="p-3"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Using React Functional Component + React Hooks

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve({
        "result": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "john",
            "age": "35"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "johnson",
            "age": "25"
          }
        ]
      })).then((response) => {
        setData(response.result);
      });
    };
    
    fetch();
  }, []);
  
  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const headings = Object.keys(data[0]);

  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead className="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          {headings.map((heading) => <th>{heading}</th>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((row) => (
          <tr>
            {headings.map((heading) => <td>{row[heading]}</td>)}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="root" class="p-3"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this without using hooks as I'm not using hooks in my project. 
It is throwing error Hooks can only be used inside of the body of the function component.

Comment: @Kalyan Updated the solution with an example using the React Class API

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdggE.png I made changes accordingly,this is how i am getting the data..

Comment: @Kalyan Please update your question with a JSON representation of the data you fed to the code.

Comment: I have updated the JSON according to the screenshot. Please check it and also do you know the reason why I'm getting data like in the screenshoot I pasted above.

Comment: @Kalyan Other parts of your application is broken. Your example JSON will work if you followed my answer.

Comment: Your answer is working separately for me. As you said there is some code error in my code.. trying to fix it.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9q9L.png this is what i am getting now ,I believe this happening because i am checking an condition before showing the table heading 
This is code which i am using for displaying table heading :-
 <thead>
          <tr>
        {this.state.apiResponseData.length!=0?( 
          <div>
           {Object.keys(this.state.apiResponseData[0]).map((heading)=><th key={heading}>{heading}</th>)}
           </div>
  ):(
    <tr></tr>
  )} 
 </tr> 
  </thead>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214339/discussion-between-win-and-kalyan).

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to store the object you are getting from your backend in a useState hook. You will also want to track how many fields the user has selected with a useState hook. Something like this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null); // no initial data
const [fields, setFields] = useState(2); // 2 initial fields selected
```

Now you can update the fields state with a method within your function that gets called every time the value changes. Then you want to query your backend with a useEffect hook and pass in the new field value from the backend.

```js
const updateFields = (event) => {
  setFields(event.target.value);
}

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`backend/api/?fields=${fields}`)
    .then(res => {
      setData(res.body);
    })
});
```

As per the comment, if you're not using hooks, you can use `ComponentDidMount` instead of `useEffect` and create a similar update method.

```js
const updateFields = (event) => {
  this.setState({ fields: event.target.value });
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`backend/api/?fields=${fields}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ data:  res.data });
  })
}
```

Now you can return JSX that has a field to set the field number as well as map through the data object to set a dynamic table of values. If you're not using hooks, place the `this` keyword to reference state (i.e. `this.data` instead of `data`).

```js
return (
  <input onChange={(e) => updateFields(e)} />

  <table>
    <thead>
      {Object.keys(data[0]).map((el) => {
        <th key={el}>{el}</th>
      })
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((el, i) => {
        {Object.keys(data[i]).map((elKey) => <td key={elKey}>{el[elKey]}</td>)}
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
);
```

These are two great resources for understanding more about querying data:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/

And this is a good resource for understanding more about mapping over objects in React:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using hooks as I'm not using it in my project. If I write this using hooks I need to change the code I already wrote. I'm using class and state variables

Comment: @Kalyan I updated the code for without hooks. I am assuming you already have state variables declared, so I did not update the initial hooks code snippet.

Comment: I have update the code as per your answer, now getting table heading & data but there is a problem like under one heading column the entire table data is coming and other headings don't have any data. 

Please check the below link...

Answer (score 0):

How about conditionally rendering the cells?
Like:

```
data.map(item => (
    {item.age? <td>{item.age}</td>: null}
))
```

Comment: everytime the data which comes changes based on the user input so I can't use the above stated

Answer (score 0):

Every time user selects fields, store the field name in a variable.
Ex:

```
const Header = [{"title":"Name","index":"name"}]
```

Make sure the `key` matches with the array index which you get from server(API).

Then create anew component for rendering table and pass `data` and `headers` to that as `props`

Then extract the headers to an array and before rendering data, just check if the specific value exists

```
const viewTable = (props) => { 
    const index = []; 
    const header = props.header.map((heading) => { 
        index.push(heading.index); 
        return <th key={heading.index}>{heading.title}</th> 
    }); 

    const tableData = props.data.map((data, key) => { 
        return <tr>
             {index.map(key => {
                 if (index.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                     return <td>{row[key]}</td>;
                 }
             })}
          </tr>
    }) ; 

    return ( 
        <table cellSpacing={30} cellPadding={5}> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    {header} 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                {tableData} 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    ); 
} 

export default viewTable;
```